# Strange error trying to read registry value with Windows/C++

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I'm trying to read the install path for an application, and I'm baffled at the behaviour I'm getting. First, here's the code that didn't work (formatted it a little so it doesn't take up a huge line):

```
LONG status = RegQueryValueEx(
    hkRegistry,
    "InstallPath",
    0,
    &regType, (LPBYTE)installPath,
    &regSize );
if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    // Handle success.
}
```

I realized that it was failing on the call to `RegQueryValueEx`, so I decided to probe the return value by throwing it within an exception by adding:

```
else {
    throw Exception( status );
}
```

But then... the code started to work and the call to `RegQueryValueEx` succeeded. I've been able to repeat this behaviour as long as I throw *something* within the `else`. If I comment out the body of the else, the error returns.

**Edit:** Okay, I tried calling `MessageBox` instead of an exception and I get the same behaviour. If I comment it out, it stops working again.

Is there a rational explanation for this?

Comment: Could you give some more information, such as the declarations of all the variables (or preferably even the entire function in which this is called)? I could imagine this being some kind of stack overflow problem where the symptoms vary based on how the compiler decides to layout the stack based on the rest of the function.

Comment: I realized that might've been what was happening, and I came back here and you confirmed it (strange how that always happens with my questions).   When I finally got it to behave 'properly' and show me the `RegQueryValueEx` error, it was `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, so what was likely happening was that since the buffer was too small, with a certain stack layout, it would imply overflow onto other stack elements, but when I changed the code around, there was a gap between them so it couldn't do that. I'm in utopia right now; you can respond with this information and I'll accept it.

Comment: Make sure you initialize regSize!

Comment: @Jengerer: Glad I could help. :) I've added an answer to that effect.

Comment: @bdonlan: Yes, I thought at first that it was used simply to return the size that was filled out, but then I did the unthinkable: I read the MSDN docs and realized that makes a lot more sense! The wonders that will do! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the buffer for `installPath` is too small compared to the value contained in `regSize` (which must be initialized to the size of the buffer).

If `installPath` is a stack-allocated value I suspect that it is overflown, causing the value of `status` to get overwritten.